# CSS: 2nd hovered action on already hovered element (z-index?)

Tags: css, hover, z-index

I'm building a clone of this application. The .gif is what i'm trying to replicate.

I have an `Email` component that has a hover action to change the background color. Within that component there's a Next.js `<Image/>` component that should have *another* hover action on it as well.

How do you "stack" hover actions? I tried setting the `z-index` to 1 for the `Email` and 10 for the `Image` with another hover action on the `Image` but that didn't work. Do I need z-index? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `:hover` style for the child element the same way you would for the parent. `z-index` is not relevant.

```css
div:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>hello</span> there
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/goshdarnheck/pen/yLXOpgL